# Qual a razão de existir um limite diário de pontuação?

Tags: debate

Qual a razão de existir um limite diário de pontuação?

O site não receberia mais contribuições caso não existisse um limite diário?

Com a ausência de um limite diário o site certamente receberia mais contribuições.

Comment: Se quiser mais detalhes tem alguma explicação em inglês: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/140010. Na verdade tem outras que eu não consegui achar, tem alguns bons motivos como evitar manipulação, não deixar algumas pessoas desgarrar demais e não viciar demais a pessoa :) Tem esse motivo técnico importante tb: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/140010

Comment: Entendi o motivo, mas acho que deveriam por ele na página de ajuda... postei lá: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283879/why-not-explain-the-reasons-for-daily-reputation-limit-on-the-help-page

Comment: Acredito que o Help já tenha bastante informação, a intenção dele não é fazer um livro com todos os fatos. Resumido a maioria já não lê. O meta serve para informações secundárias.

Comment: O help já tá com informação até demais na minha opinião, esse tipo de dúvida se encaixa melhor perguntado nos metas, como você fez. Encher o help de informação nem adianta, fica cansativo e ninguém(ou poucos) acaba lendo.

Answer (score 9):

**Não acho** que remover o limite diário traria benefícios e muito menos respostas boas.

Quem esta aqui somente pelos pontos provavelmente não trará  respostas boas (*não falando de você, mas sim do geral*), as respostas boas são de quem quer colaborar, independente da pontuação.

A *pontuação* é algo **apenas** para incentivar, **o que importa é a qualidade do conteúdo**, ou seja, recursos do site como medalhas e pontos são para incentivar a participação, mesmo que os pontos ainda sirvam para coisas extras, como recompensar respostas.

## Motivos para limitar os pontos:

- Evitar atingir privilégios rapidamente sem realmente merecer tais privilégios ou estar habituado a comunidade o suficiente e usar mal os privilégios ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))
- Score funciona em parte como um moeda local, ou seja quanto mais pontos, mais coisas poderá fazer (além do privilégios), coisas como dar mais downvotes, lançar mais recompensas ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty))

**Resumindo**, é uma questão de segurança para a comunidade, é como um jogo, se você consegue evoluir muito rápido, mas não tem o grau de *maturidade* necessário, é bem possível que venha a causar problemas.

Limitar a pontuação diário não foi criado por a acaso, tudo tem um motivo e pode ter certeza são sempre ótimos motivos **para a comunidade** e não para o individuo.

Então seja paciente

Comment: Realmente "MATURIDADE" é a palavra chave. Sugestão: O texto que explica sobre o limite diário, explica apenas como ele funciona, mas não a razão. Poderia ter alguma explicação sobre a razão deste limite lá.

Comment: @AllanAndrade muita coisa foi definida no blog, equipe, empresa, antes do Help ser mais completo. Realmente seria legal explicar os motivos. Todavia é algo que somente os devs podem resolver, talvez sugerir no METÃO (meta.stackexchange.com). Ainda sim o meta.pt.stackoverflow está aqui para tirar essas duvidas ;)

Comment: Nasciment, postei lá: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283879/why-not-explain-the-reasons-for-daily-reputation-limit-on-the-help-page

Comment: Imagina as pessoas ainda falando "Onde põem cash, para que eu possa ganhar pontos em dobro?".

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert HUEHUEHUE XD é bem capaz mesmo